# Spring Boot : how to update object efficently?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Hello everyone I'm new to Spring world. Actually I want to know how can we use converter to update object  instead of updating each element one by one using set and get. Right now in my controller I've :

```
    @PostMapping("/edit/{userId}")
    public Customer updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer newCustomer, @PathVariable final String userId)
    {
        return customerService.update(userId, newCustomer);
    }
```

and this is how I'm updating the customer object :

```
    @Override
    public Customer update(String id, Customer newCustomer) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(id).get();

        customer.setFirstName(newCustomer.getFirstName());
        customer.setLastName(newCustomer.getLastName());
        customer.setEmail(newCustomer.getEmail());

        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Instead of using each time set and get, I want to use a converter.

Comment: For what is worth, it is not a good practice to use your database object as your endpoint request body. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach of passing the entity's id as a path variable when you're updating it isn't really right. Think about this: you have a `@RequestBody`, why don't you include the id inside this body too? Why do you want to specify a path variable for it?

Now, if you have the full `Customer` with its id from the body, you don't have to make any calls to your repository because hibernate adds it to a `persistent` state already based on its id and a simple

```
public Customer update(Customer newCustomer) {
      return customerRepository.save(newCustomer);
}
```

should work.

**Q:** What is a persistent state?

**A:** A persistent entity has been associated with a database table row and it’s being managed by the current running Persistence Context. ( `customerRepository.findById()` is just asking the DB if the entity with the specified id exists and add it to a persistent state. Hibernate manage all this process if you have an `@Id` annotated field and is filled, in other words:

```
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   customer.setId(1);
```

is *ALMOST* the same thing as :

```
   Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(1).get();
```

)

**TIPS:** Anyway, you shouldn't have (if you didn't know) a model in the controller layer.  Why? Let's say that your `Customer` model can have multiple permissions. One possible structure could look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
   //private fields here;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",--other configs here--)
   private List<Permission> permissions;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Permission{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(--configs here--)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

You can see that you have a cross reference between `Customer` and `Permission` entity which will eventually lead to a stack overflow exception (if you don't understand this, you can think about a recursive function which doesn't have a condition to stop and it's called over and over again => stack overflow. The same thing is happening here).

What can you do? Creating a so called `DTO` class that you want the client to receive instead of a model. How can you create this DTO? Think about what the user **NEEDS** to know.

1) Is "creationDate" from `Permission` a necessary field for the user? Not really.

2) Is "id" from `Permission` a necessary  field for the user? In some cases yes, in others, not.

A possible `CustomerDTO` could look like this:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private List<String> permissions;
}
```

and you can notice that I'm using a `List<String>` instead of `List<Permission>` for customer's permissions which are in fact the permissions' names.

```
public CustomerDTO convertModelToDto(Customer customer)
{
    //hard way
    CustomerDTO customerDTO = new CustomerDTO();
    customerDTO.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
    customerDTO.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
    customerDTO.setPermissions(
       customer.getPermissions()
               .stream()
               .map(permission -> permission.getName())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    );

    // easy-way => using a ModelMapper
    customerDTO = modelMapper.map(customer,CustomerDTO.class);

    return customerDTO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelMapper` to map one model into another.
First define a function that can map source data into the target model. Use this as a library to use whenever want.

```
  public static <T> void merge(T source, T target) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    modelMapper.map(source, target);
  }
```

Use `merge` for mapping data

```
Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(id).get();
merge(newCustomer, customer);
customerRepository.save(customer);
```

Add dependency in pom.xml for model mapper

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```